# Клонировать систему с одного SSD на другой

Tags: ssd, cluster

У меня отдельное SSD под систему, я купил новое SSD, так как на старом не хватает места. Чтобы не сносить систему, я хочу клонировать систему с одного ссд на другой, и поставить новый ссд вместо старого. Проблема в том, что на старом ссд размер сектора(!) 512 байт, на новом 4 Кб, и все программы, которыми я пытался клонировать систему не разрешали этого делать, так как на старом ссд размер сектора меньше, чем на новом. Как решить подобную проблему, как правильно клонировать ссд?

Comment: Какую систему - Windows или Linux? И нельзя ли просто изменить размер кластера?

Comment: @Qwertiy, Windows, ну то есть у меня ссд только под систему. Размеры кластеров равны, проблема в размере сектора

Comment: @Dr.Russel, а нельзя изменить размер сектора, форматнув новый ссд?